# Matching typescript definition module declaration to node module importing

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsd

I have installed the popular `d3` library through `NPM`.

```
npm install d3
tsd install d3 -save
tsc
```

In my `home.ts` file, I have imported the module:

`import * as d3 from 'd3/d3';`

This compiles correctly, but I get this semantic error:

`app/home/components/home.ts(2,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'd3/d3'.`

Also, I lose all of my syntax highlighting/type-ahead info in my IDE.

The original `d3.d.ts` file provided by `TSD` declares the module like so:

```
declare module 'd3' {
    export = d3;
}
```

If I change the module to `'d3/d3'`, everything works fine:

```
declare module 'd3/d3' {
    export = d3;
}
```

So, I'm having a hard time getting both of what I need:

`import * as d3 from 'd3';` gives me the type definitions I expect, but looks for a module in `node_modules/d3.js` which is incorrect.

`import * as d3 from 'd3/d3';` finds the correct module because the path is right, but i lose my type definitions because the module declaration doesn't match.

How can I get these two things to match up so I can simply import the module without losing my type definitions?

FYI: I am using typescript 1.7.5, and my `moduleResolution` is set to `node`.

Comment: Are you sure that Node will try to load `node_modules/d3.js`? I tried it on my end and it currently works both with TypeScript loading the correct typings and Node loading `node_modules/d3/d3.js`.

Comment: Did you ever get his resolved @JMac? I'm running into this exact issue tonight.

Comment: I did not...I ended up writing a hacky `declare` statement to get things to work, but it definitely isn't ideal or a real solution.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, any solution 6 weeks later? :)

Comment: I have no idea how you find out that both `import` and `declare` should refer `d3/d3`, but that definitely saved me a couple of hours. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the loader where to look for things. In your     `systemjs.config.js`, add the following mapping in the `map` object:

```
var map= {
...
...
'd3':  'node_modules/d3'
};
```

The `d3.js` file is indeed located in `node_modules/d3` and the above mapping will let the loader find the file. Now, you can import it in your components as:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```